# VMI image analysis

Tags: experimental-physics, spectroscopy, imaging

I used VMI for the photodissociation of O2 and I wonder how I can correlate the radius with the actual velocity of the fragments.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Chris, please consider expand acronyms/abbreviations so that less-familiar might understand what you mean

Comment: Velocity Map Imaging - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photofragment-ion_imaging. or http://web.sas.upenn.edu/lestergroup/velocity-map-imaging/ for a better graphic.

Comment: Thanks Kyle Kanos, you are right!

@mmesser314, I cannot figure how, for example in the second link, the pixel radius is correlated to TKER, is there some universal conversion factor?